# Improve multithreading with network IO and database queries

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, mysql-python, pycurl

I'm writing a script that:

1. fetch a list of urls from a db (about 10000 urls)
2. download all the pages and insert them into the db
3. parse the code
4. if(some condition) do other inserts into the db

I have a Xeon quad-core with hyper-threading, so a total of 8 thread available and I'm under Linux (64 bit).

I'm using `cStringIO` as buffer, `pycurl` to fetch the pages, `BeautifulSoup` to parse them and `MySQLdb` to interact with the database.

I tried to simplify the code below (removing all the try/except, parsing operation, ...).

```
import cStringIO, threading, MySQLdb.cursors, pycurl

NUM_THREADS = 100
lock_list = threading.Lock()
lock_query = threading.Lock()


db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "...", user = "...", passwd = "...", db = "...", cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT...")
rows = cur.fetchall()
rows = [x for x in rows]  # convert to a list so it's editable


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        """ initialize a StringIO object and a pycurl object """

        while True:
            lock_list.acquire()  # acquire the lock to extract a url
            if not rows:  # list is empty, no more url to process
                lock_list.release()
                break
            row = rows.pop()
            lock_list.release()

            """ download the page with pycurl and do some check """

            """ WARNING: possible bottleneck if all the pycurl
                connections are waiting for the timeout """

            lock_query.acquire()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO ...")  # insert the full page into the database
            db.commit()
            lock_query.release()

            """do some parse with BeautifulSoup using the StringIO object"""

            if something is not None:
                lock_query.acquire()
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO ...")  # insert the result of parsing into the database
                db.commit()
                lock_query.release()


# create and start all the threads
threads = []
for i in range(NUM_THREADS):
    t = MyThread()
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# wait for threads to finish
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I use `multithreading` so I don't need to wait if some requests are going to fail for timeout. That specific thread will wait but the others are free to continue with the other urls.

[Here](http://i48.tinypic.com/aw2a2p.png) a screenshot while doing nothing but the script. It seems that 5 cores are busy while the other are not. So the questions are:

- should I create as many cursors as the number of threads?
- do I really need to lock the execution of a query? What happened if a thread execute a *cur.execute()* but not the *db.commit()* and another thread come in doing the *execution + commit* with another query?
- I read about the [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) class, but I'm not sure if I understood correctly: can I use it instead of doing *lock + extract a url + release*?
- using `multithreading` can I suffer from I/O (network) bottleneck? With 100 threads my speed doesn't exceed ~500Kb/s while my connection can go faster. If I move to `multiprocess` will I see some improvement on this side?
- the same question but with MySQL: using my code, there could be a bottleneck on this side? All those *lock + insert query + release* can be improved in some way?
- if the way to go is `multithreading`, is 100 an high number of threads? I mean, too many threads doing I/O requests (or DB queries) are useless because of the mutual exclusion of these operations? Or more threads means more network speed?

Comment: [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate for this kind of questions.

Comment: it's worth trying multiprocessing. I believe the only thing you would need to is is replace `threading.Thread` with `multiprocessing.Process` to test it out.

Comment: see this about [threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Comment: see this about [autocommit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/innodb-and-autocommit.html)

Comment: @COpython I already tried that, both CPU and network usage seems to increase but the script is looping so I don't know the cause of better performance.

Comment: @Luca multiprocessing tends to generally be faster than threading, due to modern processors being optimized better for multiple processes rather than threads.

Comment: @didierc the problem in [threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) is that it advises to switch to multiprocessing to avoid GIL, but it also advises to stay on threads for betteer I/O performance. And I don't want to use autocommit

Comment: then I guess your code is OK. Be careful with your test on `rows`: there's an `else` missing somewhere.

Comment: @didierc thanks for the heads up, but as I wrote somewhere, I simplified the code removing all the control, to make the post shorter

Comment: yeah, I thought so, but I mentioned it just in case. perhaps you should update the question code.